# Theorem 7.11 in Scholze's $p$-adic Hodge Theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, rigid-analytic-geometry, p-adic-hodge-theory

I was trying to understand the statement and proof of Theorem 7.11 in Scholze's paper "$p$-adic Hodge Theory for Rigid-Analytic Varieties". I'll reproduce part of the statement below:

> Let $X$ be a proper smooth adic space over $\mathrm{Spa}(k, \mathcal O_{k})$ (where $k$ is some complete discretely valued field extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ with perfect residue field). Let $(\mathcal E, \nabla, \mathrm{Fil}^\bullet)$ be a filtered $\mathcal O_X$ module with integrable connection, giving rise to a ${\mathbb B} _ {\mathrm{dR}}^+$ local system $\mathbb M$. Let $\bar k$ denote an algebraic closure of $k$ with completion $\hat{\bar k}$. Then, there is a $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar k/k)$-equivariant isomorphism $$H^i(X_ {\bar k}, \mathrm{gr}^0\mathbb M) \cong \bigoplus_j H^{i-j, j}_ {\mathrm{Hodge}}(X, \mathcal E) \otimes_k \hat{\bar k}(-j),$$
> where $H^{i-j, j}_{\mathrm{Hodge}}(X, \mathcal E) := H^i(X, \mathrm{gr}^j(DR(\mathcal E)) )$, where the de Rham complex $DR(\mathcal E)$ has the natural filtration induced by Griffith's transversality.

Here are my questions:

1. (This is more a confirmation that I am parsing the notation correctly) I assume that $H^i(X, \mathrm{gr}^i(DR(\mathcal E)))$ is the functor $H^i(X, -): D(\mathcal O_X) \to \mathcal O_X(X)-\mathrm{Mod}$ applied to the complex $\mathrm{gr}^j(DR(\mathcal E))$? In particular, these Hodge cohomology groups are $k$ vector spaces that have no Galois action, right?
2. After a series of reductions, to prove the theorem one reduces to showing that $$H^i(X_{\bar k}, \mathcal A) \otimes_{\bar k} \hat{\bar k} \cong H^i(X_{\bar k}, \mathcal A\otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathrm{gr}^0 \mathcal O \mathbb B_{dR})$$
   for all $i\ge 0$. It is then claimed that the right hand side is $H^i(X_{\hat{\bar k}, an}, \mathcal A_{\hat{\bar k}})$, by covering $X$ with affinoid open subsets on which $\mathcal A$ becomes free and using the following lemma:

> For $U$ affinoid of finite type over $\bar k$ such that $U$ admits an etale map to a torus that factors as a composition of rational embeddings and finite 'etale maps, $$ H^q(U, \mathrm{gr}^0\mathcal O\mathbb B_{dR})$$ is $\mathcal O_U(U)$ for $q=0$, and is zero for $q\ge 1$.

I'm struggling to see how this fact implies the claim. This is what I thought: We may suppose $X$ is affinoid and $X_{\bar k}$ satisfies the conditions of the previous lemma, and then we write $$H^i(X_{\bar k}, \mathcal A\otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathrm{gr}^0 \mathcal O \mathbb B_{dR}) = \bigoplus_j H^j(X_{\bar k}, \mathcal A) \otimes_{\mathcal O_X(X)} H^{i-j}(X_{\bar k}, \mathrm{gr}^0\mathcal O\mathbb B_{dR})$$
and all but one of the direct summands on the right hand side are 0 by the lemma. This proof seems extremely dubious to me and I think something more clever is going on, but I can't see what.

3. Finally, to prove the Hodge decomposition, Scholze claims that $$\bigoplus_ j H^i(X_ {\bar k}, \mathrm{gr}^j(DR(\mathcal E))) \otimes_{\bar k} \mathrm{gr}^{-j} B_ {dR} = \bigoplus_j H^{i-j,j}_ {\mathrm{Hodge}} (X, \mathcal E) \otimes_ k \hat{\bar k}(-j).$$
   It seems like the above identification implicitly uses the fact that $$H^i(X_ {\bar k}, \mathrm{gr}^j(DR(\mathcal E))) = H^i(X, \mathrm{gr}^j(DR(\mathcal E))) \otimes_ k {\bar k},$$
   but I don't see why this is true - why can we just "pull" the $\bar k$ out?